# Where and why are there metric road signs in Arizona?

Tags: usa, road-signs, arizona, measurements

A road sign from Arizona:

[image: Arizona using metric?]

Came across this from the web, found it curious. Traditionally the US, Burma and Liberia, I believe, don't use metric. But there are metric road signs in Arizona?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77360/discussion-on-question-by-mark-mayo-where-and-why-are-there-metric-road-signs-in).

Comment: You could try drawing a circle of radius 4km centered at Amado, a circle of radius 29km centered at Green Valley, and a circle of radius 67km centered at Tucson, and then (triangulating) see where all three circles meet.

Comment: @FixedPoint Won't be precise since they're road miles, not straight-line miles. Amado is so small anyway, there's only one highway through it, and road signs only show what's in front of you, so it's I-19 4 km south of Amado. (Technically it's trilaterating since you aren't measuring angles)

Comment: Burma went metric.

Comment: @Harper Congrats, Burma

Answer (score 74, accepted):

That photo looks like I-19 in Arizona, [America's only metric road](http://www.cnn.com/interactive/2015/07/us/metric-road-american-story/) ([more from Atlas Obscura](https://www.atlasobscura.com/places/i19-americas-only-metric-interstate)).

Congress passed the Metric Conversion Act in 1975, the last time the US had a serious metric system push, and various tests were carried out to start the conversion process. I-19 in Arizona was one of the test sites. After widespread opposition ("Forcing the American people to convert to the metric system goes against our democratic principles" is a quote from Chuck Grassley in 1977, and the guy has not mellowed out since then), the Metric Board was eventually disbanded.

[But the locals like it](https://www.arizonahighways.com/blog/interstate-19-miles-or-kilometers):

> Our bosses at the Arizona Department of Transportation have tried to change I-19's signs back to miles before. The signs have to be replaced periodically anyway. But businesses along the highway say doing so would make their shops harder to find, since the exit numbers would also change.

They tried to [change the signs back to miles as recently as 2009](https://www.nogalesinternational.com/news/adot-defends-replacing-metric-signs-along-i/article_47be9930-829e-579c-8c88-a706dee9cd40.html), but [there was local opposition](http://www.tucsonsentinel.com/local/report/021010_metric/i-19-metric-to-miles-switch-doesnt-measure-up-some/) that put the plan on hold. [The issue came up again in 2014](https://www.azcentral.com/story/news/local/arizona/2014/10/04/arizona-highway-signs-in-metric-units-may-change/16724615/), still without any change.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77397/discussion-on-answer-by-zach-lipton-where-and-why-are-there-metric-road-signs-in).

Answer (score 8):

Appears as though it was a timing situation when it was built, during a brief law change.

[Gizmodo has an article on it](https://www.gizmodo.com.au/2014/10/an-arizona-highway-has-used-the-metric-system-since-the-1980s/):

> That made sense in 1980, when I-19's signs first went up and when US
>   was near the peak of its flirtation with the metric system. Five years
>   earlier, President Ford had signed the Metric Conversion Act,
>   declaring the metric system "the preferred system of weights and
>   measures for United States trade and commerce" and establishing United
>   States Metric Board to guide the conversion. Schoolchildren dutifully
>   learned their kilograms and centimetres.
>
> But the Metric Conversion Act was only voluntary, and there was far
>   too much inertia to change every single label in the country
>   voluntarily. Reagan disbanded the Metric Board in 1982. Instead of
>   leading the charge into brave new metric system, Arizona's highway is
>   a reminder of a failed experiment.

Answer (score 2):

I'm willing to bet that this sign is from a place close to the Mexican border. I live in San Diego, CA, a city close to the Mexican border, and I've seen a few road signs in my area with metric units (actually, both metric and Customary units).

The reason why those metric signs exist is because frequently, people driving on those roads are often tourists from Mexico, driving cars that were built for the metric system (speedometer and odometer measure in metric units). This sign was put up for the benefit of people who are driving such cars, especially older cars that lack alternate scales for the Customary system.

You might even see similar signs in places close to the Canadian border, especially in areas frequented by Canadian tourists.

Comment: No, UK still uses miles/yards and MPH on their signs. Weight limits are in metric tons (<2% off a imperial ton anyway). Length and height limits are foot-inch but are now migrating to dual units.

Comment: @user71659 Clarified it.

Comment: It's worth noting that the first sentence of this post (as it was at the time I commented, though it's since been removed) is literally correct.  Whilst the UK still continues to use imperial units in certain contexts, the imperial and US Customary Unit systems are [not the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_the_imperial_and_US_customary_measurement_systems), and confusion can arise if wrong assumptions are made.  Myanmar also uses imperial units, though it's transitioning to SI.

Comment: @MadHatter: While some US and UK units differ (most importantly, the volume ones, such as pints, which are still widely used in both the US and UK), the length units that are relevant for this question (miles, feet, inches) are identical in the US and UK, as your link shows.

Comment: @PLL But miles aren't miles :D  Ask someone in the US to drive 400 miles, and they'd be like OK that's just going to the other end of the state, whereas in the UK they'd respond .. jeez you want me to drive half the length of the UK?!?!?!?!

Comment: @PLL the difference in use is a little confusing at first.  In the US it's common to say 1000ft, and yards are rarer; in the UK feet aren't really used in driving but yards are common (up to about 400, then fractions of a mile).  The conversion is of course simple (1000ft is near enough 300m!)

Comment: @PeterM, no, that's only halfway across the state. ;-)

Comment: @PLL: FWIW The US survey mile is ever so slightly longer than the international mile. As far as I understand it both are used in the US, in different circumstances (though the difference is so tiny it will rarely make any difference).

Comment: @psmears Specifically, the difference is about 2 parts per million, so, in practice, no one cares which one they're using. Surveyors would probably care the most, but even they don't care in practice, since their equipment usually isn't that precise, anyway.

Comment: @reirab, to put it in context, two parts per million is an error of 29 feet in measuring the distance from New York to Los Angeles -- although I'm pretty sure a surveyor using modern equipment could spot that much error.

Comment: @Mark They could spot the error if measuring the distance from NYC to LA, but they'd be much less likely to spot it when measuring a property line that is, say, 100 ft. long (a more typical use case for a surveyor.) 2 ppm of 100 feet would be 2.4 thousandths of an inch. :)